# Difference between an $R$-algebra being finitely generated and finite

Tags: ring-theory, modules

So I have the two following definitions:

An $R$-algebra $S$ is said to be finite over $R$ if it is finitely generated as an $R$-Module.

An $R$-algebra $S$ is said to be finitely generated if $$S \cong R[x_{1},x_{2}, \dots x_{n}]/I$$
for some $n$ and some ideal $I$.

Do these two definitions mean the same thing?

Comment: I think the second one means finitely generated as a ring while the first requires finitely generated as a module.  Finitely generated as a module is generally a much stronger condition.  But it depends on the ring $R$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not at all: $R[x]$ is generated by $x$ as an $R$-algebra, but it's a free $R$-module with an infinite basis.

Actually a finitely generated $R$-algebra is finite if and only if its generators (as an algebra) are integral over $R$.

Comment: Ahh, so its a bit like field extensions, where the field $K(x_{1},x_{2},\dots,x_{n})$ is a finitely generated field extension of $K$ but it is only finite over $K$ when each of the $x_{i}$'s are algebraic over $K$, so this is just a generalisation of that?

Comment: Exactly. The ring of integers of an algebraic number field is a finite $\mathbf Z$-module. However, a finite algebra  can be very far from this canonical example: $\,\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ is also a finite $\mathbf Z$-module.